# Replace variable names in text string with actual values

Tags: vb.net, email, text, merge

I am writing a program  in VB2022 to manage the running of a yachting regatta.
As part of this I want to include a  mail merge module for sending results to the competitors.
I have it mostly running, however I am having trouble getting the merge file to display the actual values.
The text file is initially in this form

> Dear {XtianName}
>
> Thank you for participating in our {CurrentRegatta} regatta.
>
> Here are the results of this regatta, and your individual results.
>
> The overall winner of the Regatta was {SeriesWinner} with
> {WinnersPoints} Points.
>
> Your yacht {YtName} was placed {SeriesPlace} with {SeriesPoints}
> points. etc etc

(These variables are in a list, from which the user can pick the appropriate one, and paste it into the letter)

Once the user composes the letter, it is sent to a Function which modifies it, so it looks like this.

```
"Dear " & XtianName & "

Thank you for participating in our " & CurrentRegatta & " regatta.

Here are the results of this regatta, and your individual results.

The overall winner of the Regatta was " & SeriesWinner & " with " & WinnersPoints & " Points.

Your yacht " & YtName & " was placed " & SeriesPlace & " with " & SeriesPoints & " points." etc
```

Which is where the problem arises.

if I test this by pasting this file into the program, like this,

```
dim NewMergeFile as string ="Dear " & XtianName & "

Thank you for participating in our " & CurrentRegatta & " regatta."  etc.

then

Msgbox(NewMergeFile)
```

the variable names have been replaced by the actual values.

But what I wanted to happen was that the 'NewMergeFile' would itself have the actual values, so I could save it, and send it to the printer, or email or whatever.

I'm sure I am missing a step somewhere, but I can't think where.

I've tried everything I can think of, and looked extensively here, and on other programming sites, but no one else appears to be having this exact problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any coding.  You can do this in Word using the MailMerge options without using VB at all.  You create your template document with Word {fields} to be substituted, then provide an Excel spreadsheet (or other data source) with the substitution values.  One button produces all your letters.

Comment: Thanks Tim,  I did consider this,  but I can't be sure any potential user will have word on their computer. I was hoping to make the whole thing seamless, without having to use any external programs. May have to take this route if I can't do it the way I envisage.

Comment: It seems like your missing step is to write the updated file to whatever the output location should be (probably *not* replacing the existing file since that's intended to be a template).

Comment: Thank's James Z.  Looks more readable. You don't happen to have a solution to my problem do you ?  Still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-8.0) to replace markers in a string with values you specify.

```
Dim messageTemplate as string = "Your yacht '{0}' was placed {1} with {2} points."
Dim boatName as string = "Swifty McBoatFace"
Dim boatPosition as string = "2nd"
Dim boatPoints as integer = 100
Dim formattedMessage as string = string.Format(messageTemplate, boatName, boatPosition, boatPoints)
```

The result of formattedMessage would be "Your yacht 'Swifty McBoatFace' was placed 2nd with 100 points".

Comment: Thanks Hobbes, Your example works fine.  Just have to see how i can apply that to my application.  Do I have to specify every used variable in the String.Format arguments

Comment: @BarryTNU yes, you do.

Comment: @BarryTNU As HardCode said, yes, you do need to supply an argument for each variable. You can, however, repeat the variables and/or place them out of order. So if the template string was "Boat '{0}' won, congrats to '{0}'" you only have to specify an argument for {0} once, e.g. String.Format(messageTemplate, "Swifty McBoatFace") and it will replace both instances of {0} with the supplied argument.

Comment: @Hobbes  I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. On further searching it seems String interpolation might be the way to go.  My initial format "

    Dear {XtianName}

    Thank you for participating in our {CurrentRegatta} regatta.

    Here are the results of this regatta, and your individual results.

    The overall winner of the Regatta was {SeriesWinner} with {WinnersPoints} Points.

    Your yacht {YtName} was placed {SeriesPlace} with {SeriesPoints} points. etc etc"  with the addition of $" at the beginning works when written into the program,  but

Comment: @Hobbes  >>  but the variables are not being replaced by the actual values when I save the file.  What I am hoping to do is load the mail merge template, and run it  for each yacht for later printing or emailing. I thought this would be trivial,  but it seems I am wrong, again .